# Gridview event to access controls in ItemTemplate & EditItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012

Is there one gridview event that can access a control in `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate` without additional code (ie. session, viewstate, etc)?

Let's say my gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Sales" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="SalesId" 
OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
OnRowEditing="GridView_NSB_RowEditing"
OnRowUpdating="GridView_NSB_RowUpdating" 
OnRowCommand="GridView_NSB_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sold">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_WasSold" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WasSold").ToString() %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Sold" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"> </asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="No"> </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

`GridView_RowDataBound` has access to `Label_WasSold` in `ItemTempplate` but not the dropdown in `EditItemTemplate`. `GridView_RowEditing` has access to `DropDownList_Sold` but not to `Label_WasSold`; the same thing with `GridView_RowUpdating`.

I want to compare the value in `Label_WasSold.Text` to the value in `DropDownList_Sold.SelectedValue` when doing an update without having to add more code or drag session variables from one place to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a hidden field to EditTemplate that stores the value of `WasSold` data item as in code below.

In your `RowUpdating` event, you can find the hidden field and get its value, then compare it with drop down value.

*Markup to include hidden field in EditTemplate*

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sold">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label_WasSold" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WasSold").ToString() %>'>
            </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField id="hdnWasSold" runat="server"  Value='<%# Eval("WasSold").ToString() %>' />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Sold" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="No"> </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
```

*C# code to get the hidden field value in RowUpdating event*

```
HiddenField hdnWasSold = (HiddenField)GridView_Sales.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hdnWasSold");
string wasSoldValue = hdnWasSold.Value;
```

Comment: I thought there was another way besides `HiddenField`, but that'll work. Thanks.